# How do "Diamond Dash" blocks change color?

Tags: diamond-dash

In "[Diamond Dash](http://www.wooga.com/games/diamonddash/)" you click on at least 3 contiguous blocks of color to make them disappear for points.  You can see while clicking that some blocks change color to make more contiguous blocks.

What is the algorithm behind those color changes?

Comment: I'm removing the "casual" tag from your question because we have a policy to only use genre tags for questions that are *asking about the genre* or for questions about identifying the game. We don't use them for question classification due to problems like defining genres for a particular game and such.

Comment: Okay. I think that's a bad policy, since people might scan for the "casual" tag for things to read about, but I accept that it's your community.

Comment: This is how we used to go about it, but we've since changed our policy due to reasons listed [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/underused-genre-tags/1858#1858). Aside from just those issues, there's also the problem of *defining* what exactly falls under "casual," as it's not a strictly defined term. If you'd like to further discuss the policy, feel free to open a topic on Meta. :)